# substring replace from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is string

```
chat('star_comment','11211967','17','HF00008','MLR51101639100ICI100','B19','0','2020');
```

i want to replace it to like this in javascript:

```
chat('star_comment','11211967','17','HF00008','MLR51101639100ICI100','B19','RO_RX','2020');
```

my code is like this:

```
var str = "chat('star_comment','11211967','17','HF00008','MLR51101639100ICI100','B19','0','2020')";
check = "0";
var res = str.replace("/\/"+check+"\//", "RO_RX");
```

but this is not working

Comment: `str.replace("'0'", "'RO_RX'")` Why not this?

Comment: Where is the single quotes around 0 in check variable?

Comment: i want to add "/" in both side. i need to like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the replacement and put the single quotes in the selector (`check`) direcctly

```js
var str = "chat('star_comment','11211967','17','HF00008','MLR51101639100ICI100','B19','0','2020')";
let check = "'0'";
var res = str.replace(check, "'RO_RX'"); 
console.log(res);
```